# Beamer Singapore theme - section title offset problem

Tags: beamer

I am using `\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}` to create a presentation. However, I used `\setbeamertemplate{mini frames}{}` to remove the navigation dots. One of my section contains a lot of subsections than the other. So, my section headings at the top of each slide appears like this.
[image]
 Look how 'Results and discussion' is unevenly spaced. I know this is because of

1. More number of subsection in that section
2. Compress option I have used

But I don't know how to make it evenly spaced.

Is there any way to achieve this without removing `compress` option? (Removing `compress` option pushes each of slide down with unwanted space in between)

Comment: Can you add a compilable MWE that illustrates your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ripped out all the miniframes from the navigation:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{tikz} % only for the for loop
\usetheme[compress]{Singapore}

\makeatletter
\def\slideentry#1#2#3#4#5#6{%
    %section number, subsection number, slide number, first/last frame, page number, part number
    \ifnum#6=\c@part\ifnum#2>0\ifnum#3>0%
    \ifbeamer@compress%
    \advance\beamer@xpos by1\relax%
    \else%
    \beamer@xpos=#3\relax%
    \beamer@ypos=#2\relax%
    \fi%
    \fi\fi%
    \else%
    \fakeslideentry{#1}{#2}{#3}{#4}{#5}{#6}%
    \fi\ignorespaces
    }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\section{bla}

\subsection{}

\foreach \i in {1,...,30} {
    \frame{}
}

\section{very long long long long long long long long }
\frame{}

\section{very long long long long long long long long }
\frame{}

\section{blub}
\frame{}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @SaravanaKumar You're welcome!